# Adding fonts in windows 8 javascript application (@font-face)

Tags: css, windows-8

Working on windows 8 java script application, I added new font as folows:

```
  @font-face{
  font-family: "myalpha";
  src: url("/fonts/myAlpha.ttf") format('truetype');
  }
```

this produced an error:

```
@font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.
```

What does this mean? are truetype fonts are not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the embedding level of the True Type Font to `installable embedding allowed`.
You can use this [tool](http://carnage-melon.tom7.org/embed/), but make sure that the font license allows embedding.

Comment: When i run that tool, console appears and then disappears immediately.

Comment: Then run it from cmd. http://www.technixupdate.com/how-to-install-and-run-console-application-on-windows/